# Please Explain Why JS RegEx Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to extract the urls contained within all img, link, and script tags in a source code string. Using Sublime Text regex `(img|link|script).+?(href|src)="(.+?)"` finds the correct results:

=>

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/dynbm.css"
img src="assets/img/sponsor-image.png"
img class="logo" src="assets/img/sponsor-logo.png"
```

but using the following code via JS returns a random number of urls (even some but not all a tag urls):

```
var res,
    lnks = [],
    lnk_exp = new RegExp('(img|link|script).+?(href|src)="(.+?)"', 'gi');
while (res = lnk_exp.exec(src)) {
    lnks.push(res[3]);
}
console.log(lnks);
```

=>

```
[
      "assets/css/dynbm.css", 
      "/click?url=http://www.website.com/imglink", 
      "assets/img/sponsor-image.png", 
      "/click?url=http://www.website.com/link1", 
      "/click?url=http://www.website.com/link3", 
      "/click?url=http://www.website.com/cta", 
      "assets/img/sponsor-logo.png"
]
```

Full string for those interested:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/dynbm.css"><div class="dynbm_wrap rrwidth" id="dbm-name"><div id="dynbm_screens"><div class="screen" id="slide1"><div class="dynbm_body"><div class="img_right"><a href="/click?url=http://www.website.com/imglink" onclick="return sl(this,'nw','dbm-name_i1-1');"><img src="assets/img/sponsor-image.png" alt="sponsor-image"></a></div><h3><a href="/click?url=http://www.website.com/link" onclick="return sl(this,'nw','dbm-name_h1-1');">Heading</a></h3><div class="body_content"><ul><li><a href="/click?url=http://www.website.com/link1" onclick="return sl(this,'nw','dbm-name_l1-1');">Bullet 1</a></li><li><a href="/click?url=http://www.website.com/link2" onclick="return sl(this,'nw','dbm-name_l1-2');">Bullet 2</a></li><li><a href="/click?url=http://www.website.com/link3" onclick="return sl(this,'nw','dbm-name_l1-3');">Bullet 3</a></li></ul></div><p class="action_link"><a target="_parent" href="/click?url=http://www.website.com/cta" onclick="return sl(this,'nw','dbm-name_a1-1');">Learn More</a></p></div></div></div><div class="dynbm_base"><div id="sponsored_footer"><p class="sponsored_text"><a href="/www/sponsored-by" id="sponsorlnk" target="_parent">From Our Sponsor</a></p><a target="_parent" href="/click?url=http://www.website.com" onclick="return sl(this,'nw','dbm-name_logo');"><img class="logo" src="assets/img/sponsor-logo.png" alt="Logo"></a></div><div class="disclosure"><a href="#" class="close" title="Close this message" target="_parent">close</a><h4>From Our Sponsor</h4><p>Content under this heading is from or created on behalf of the named sponsor. This content is not subject to the WebMD Editorial Policy and is not reviewed by the WebMD Editorial department for accuracy, objectivity or balance.</p></div></div></div><style type="text/css">#dbm-name { background: #fff; color: #000; }</style><script type="text/javascript">(function(){var e=$('dbm-name');e.find('p.sponsored_text a, .disclosure a.close, .disclosure').click(function(){e.find('.disclosure').toggleClass('visible').css('z-index',99);return false})})()</script>`

Comment: Without knowing what the source is it's impossible to know why, or if, the code is doing what it should. Also, you're looking only for double-quoted values, which may or may not be correct.

Comment: Playing around with a [regex tester](http://regexpal.com/) might help

Comment: Try looking at `res[0]` instead of `res[3]`.  `res[3]` will only return the part after the = sign.

Comment: You're not looking for <a> tags in your regex as far as I can tell...? Is that what you're looking to do, get <a> tags?

Comment: read this on why reg exp to match html is bad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: I'm not trying to parse an HTML document. I'm simply trying to prepend a base url to some urls contained within a simple HTML string, and for that RegEx works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you need is a `<` at the beginning of your regex, which will keep it from inadvertently matching things with the substring `img|link|script`, but that aren't those types of tags, like this, from your example source:

```
img_right"><a href="/click?url=http://www.website.com/imglink"
```

Thus, the regex should be:

```
<(img|link|script).+?(href|src)="(.+?)"
```

Of course, HTML doesn't require a tag's named to be directly adjacent to the opening angle bracket, so you should have an optional number of spaces, too:

```
< *(img|link|script).+?(href|src)="(.+?)"
```

Do remember that [HTML ought not be parsed with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17339) for Real Work™.

Answer (score 0):

First, your headline is a bit sensationalist.  Of course JS RegEx works, it just doesn't work like Sublime Text's regex.

In this case, it does exactly what it [says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Fexec) it will.  `res[1]`...`res[n]` returns:

> The parenthesized substring matches, if any. The number of possible parenthesized substrings is unlimited.

Your 3rd substring in the search is everything after the equals, which it looks like you're getting output.  Just push `res[0]` instead, and you'll get the full match.

Answer (score 0):

foolish me, found the problem myself. needed to include a `<` before `img/link/script` so that   things like `/click?url=http://www.website.com/link1` aren't counted toward a `<link>` match.